# Bind class property to UWP Composition API expression

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, composition

I am trying to constantly animate a UserControl in UWP using the new Composition API. I thought about using an Expression function and binding a `Vector3 TargetPosition` class property to the expression.
But when I try the targetPosition does not get updated, only if I manually reset the value inside the Expression using `_propSet.InsertVector3("targetPos", TargetPosition);`

The following code is showing my approach:

```
public Vector3 TargetPosition;

[...]

_propSet = _rootVisual.Compositor.CreatePropertySet();
_propSet.InsertVector3("targetPos", TargetPosition);

var posAnim = ExpressionFunctions.Lerp(_rootVisual.GetReference().Offset,
            _propSet.GetReference().GetVector3Property("targetPos"),
            0.05f);

_rootVisual.StartAnimation("Offset", posAnim);
```

Is it possible to bind a class property to an UWP Composition API Expression animation? When using an other visual offset as target position the value gets updated automatically without setting it manually.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to bind a class property to an UWP Composition API Expression animation?

In UWP, the target of the binding is `DependencyProperty`, here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#every-binding-involves-these-pieces).

that means you can't set the Composition animation in the `Binding` way.

**Update**

If you want to automate something by modifying the variable (such as running an animation), you can make some adjustments for your variable.

```cs
private Vector3 _targetPosition;
public Vector3 TargetPosition
{
    get => _targetPosition;
    set
    {
        _targetPosition = value;
        DoSomething(value);
    }
}
```

This way the `DoSomething` method will be called every time you modify the `TargetPosition`.

Best regards.

Comment: I dont understand completly, so does it work when I implement the variable as DependencyProperty?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it clearly. I mean, the target being bind (not the data variable) needs to have an implementation of the dependency property. For example, `Button.Content` is the target to be bound. There is a `ContentProperty` in the Button as a dependency property, so it can be bound. But there is no dependency property implementation of the Composition animation, so this is why you can't use bindings.

Comment: Ah ok, but I want it the other way around actually. I dont want to bind the composition animation itself, i want to use a variable INSIDE the composition animation, which i want to be updated automatically when I change the variable somewhere in code, so the animation is changing. for example i have an animation that sets the visual offset based on a variable. I want to change the variable in code and then the visual offset should change as well. It works when i use a property of a visual as variable but not when using a class variable.